# How do physics bones relate to animation bones?

Tags: physics, matrix, quaternion, skinning, bones

Skinned animations use a tree of bones where the child bone (say a finger) is the weighted sum of the rotations of all it's parent bones. Physics bones are defined as a rotation matrix of a primitive (a cube) that has its position constrained by each of its child bones.

Is there any correlation with how they map to each other?
Can a physics bone be used in-place of an animation bone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it can be substituted, skinning uses matrices too. In fact, most 3D transformations involve the use of matrices. One thing though, you said weighted sum of the rotations? I thought it's supposed to be combined set of parent-child transformations in corresponding order. Anyway, just replace final combined transformation matrix of the bone with the matrix of your physics bone and see for yourself if it works out.

Comment: @Ocelot Thanks for the response. Well I have an animated mesh and a 3D physics ragdoll stick figure that I am trying to conjoin. I cant seem to figure out what the output is actually the result of (I can see it is not right, that is for sure). I am not sure if it is because the transformations are in different spaces (likely) if the animation bones and physics bones are properly corresponding, or something else...

Comment: @Ocelot I tried replacing the animation transform with a physics bone, but It seems to rotate somewhat correctly but not translate (ie. gravity). So I try and translate by the bones position and it doesnt work. Am I in the wrong space do you think? Thanks